# GWT : Set background colour for custom tree item

Tags: gwt

I have created a custom tree item ,added to the tree in my app.When a tree item is selected, i don't see the default selected background color. Should i need to set the background color , when a tree item is selected?. Or, is there a way to let GWT handle it?. I know,for a native tree item, GWT handles the selection background color.Any suggestions on how will this work for custom tree item?.

Comment: You're adding all GWT related technologies in almost each of your questions. Do you know the difference between each of them? Which tech exactly you're using?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install firebug on you firefox.
2. Select the item you're interested in
3. Check the applied css when selected and when not
4. aplly you css background rule

Best Regards,
Zied